# Using Difftime function on Multiple columns of two DataFrames in R

Tags: r, difftime

I have two data frames each containing timestamp columns as in the below 
images:

Dataframe-1:

[image: Dataframe-1]

Dataframe-2:

[image: Dataframe-2]

I want to find the time difference between each of the respective columns of the data frames, example: Time difference between respective rows of Column1 of DF1 and respective rows of Column1 of DF2.

I have only mentioned three columns in each of the data frame in the above image, although i have 257 columns in each of the column in my original dataset, i am currently finding the difference using the below command individually:

```
diff_time_1<- difftime(df1$t1,df2$l1)
diff_time_2<- difftime(df1$t2,df2$l2)..so on
```

This well take a lot of effort if i try to perform for all the 257 columns, i have tried various ways by using the apply functions and for loops, but they do not seem to work.

Kindly help me in finding a solution where i can apply the `difftime` function to the entire columns in a single go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#DATA
mydates = seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("1970-01-01"),
                     to = as.POSIXct("1970-12-01"), by = "hours")
set.seed(42)
df1 = data.frame(C1 = sample(mydates, 5), C2 = sample(mydates, 5))
df2 = data.frame(C1 = sample(mydates, 5), C2 = sample(mydates, 5))
```

If the dimension of `df1` and `df2` are same, you could just subtract to get the difference in days

```
df1 - df2
#               C1              C2
#1  152.70833 days -140.62500 days
#2   72.79167 days  -80.70833 days
#3 -216.58333 days    5.75000 days
#4  192.00000 days   60.79167 days
#5   59.91667 days   48.33333 days
```

Or you could use `sapply` to go through columns of `df1` and `df2` to use them in `difftime`

```
sapply(1:2, function(i) difftime(time1 = df1[,i], time2 = df2[,i], units = "hours"))
#      [,1]  [,2]
#[1,]  3665 -3375
#[2,]  1747 -1937
#[3,] -5198   138
#[4,]  4608  1459
#[5,]  1438  1160
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map` to apply `difftime` on corresponding columns of 'df1', 'df2' to get the a `list` of `vector`s

```
Map(difftime, df1, df2)
```

If the datetime columns are only a subset of the columns, then subset the datasets and apply `difftime`

```
Map(difftime, df1[subCols], df2[subCols])
```